# Nodejs axios error: tls_process_ske_dhe:dh key too small

Tags: node.js, axios

I confront with the following error when send request (in my local envirement):

```
write EPROTO 139893645342528:error:141A318A:SSL routines:tls_process_ske_dhe:dh key too small:../ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:2149
```

I did the following as mentioned [here](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/535):

```
// At instance level
const instance = axios.create({
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({  
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  })
});
instance.get('https://something.com/foo');

// At request level
const agent = new https.Agent({  
  rejectUnauthorized: false
});
axios.get('https://something.com/foo', { httpsAgent: agent });
```

Also I set this:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
```

But still getting the same error. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with my node version. Updated from `10.19.0` to `12.18.4` and worked just fine.